# The view or its master is not found

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In the below links I am trying to access the link labeled "merchant", while my link labeled "follower" is working just fine.  They are both accessing the same controller and view yet the one labeled "merchant" is not working.  Very confused here.

```
     <p class="lead">Register a @Html.ActionLink("Merchant", "Register", "Account", new { role = "Merchant" }, null) or Register as a @Html.ActionLink("Follower", "Register", "Account")</p>
```

I made a change the other day to try to pass the "Role" and this seems to have broken it for me.  I did change the Register method in my account controller to reflect these changes.

```
    public ActionResult Register(string role)
    {
        var model = new RegisterViewModel
          {
              Name = role
          };
     return View("Register", role);
    }
```

I also added another route config to suit this change:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
name: "Register",
url: "Account/Register/{role}",
defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" }
    );
```

Been working on this for a while and tried other similar examples listed here but this issue seems to be something else that I am not able to see.

PAths I am getting the error on, and yes the folders do exist in Account:

```
    ~/Views/Account/register.aspx
    ~/Views/Account/register.ascx
    ~/Views/Shared/register.aspx
    ~/Views/Shared/register.ascx
    ~/Views/Account/Merchant.master
    ~/Views/Shared/Merchant.master
    ~/Views/Account/Merchant.cshtml
    ~/Views/Account/Merchant.vbhtml
    ~/Views/Shared/Merchant.cshtml
    ~/Views/Shared/Merchant.vbhtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had the Register method wrong, needed to add an object param.

```
     public ActionResult Register(string role)
    {
        var model = new RegisterViewModel
          {
              Name = role
          };
        //Are these parameters accurate?
        return View("Register", new RegisterViewModel { role = role });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your Action method name and View name are same, you don't need to mention the View name explicitly, and you can pass the created model to View as below:

```
public ActionResult Register(string role)
{
    var model = new RegisterViewModel
      {
          Name = role
      };

    return View(model);
 }
```